# Android CardView without top border

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview, cardview

I'm wondering if it's possible to customize the aspect of a CardView in a way that it won't show any border line on top. I'd still like to keep the bottom border of the cardview, though. Is that possible? How could I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried applying tight marginTop so that it will basically cut out your top shadow?

Comment: You can try creating that background shape drawable and then provide that as background of cardview and if you want to do that i can give you sample of that as well